# Image does not showing up at blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I wanted to udpate `image` row of my `users` table. Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update' , ['profile' => Auth::user()->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   @method('PATCH')
   <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="image">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {{ __('Submit') }}
    </button>
</form>
```

Then I have this `update` method in my Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $profile)
{
    $validate_data = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999',
        'location' => 'nullable'
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        // get filename with extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        // get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // filename to store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // upload
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/avatars', $fileNameToStore);
    }else{
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    $user = User::findOrFail($profile);

    $user->update([
        'location' => request('location'),
        'image' => $fileNameToStore
    ]);

    $user->save();

    return back();
}
```

I have also ran the command `php artisan storage:link` to make the `storage` folder at `public` directory.

So whenever I try to upload a picture, **the image is stored successfully** at `public/storage` and at the database, and in order to retrieve it at blade, I did this:

```
<img
src="/storage/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->img }}"
alt="{{ Auth::user()->img }}"
/>
```

But the problem is, it does not show up somehow!!

So what's going wrong here, how can I display my image from db properly?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it as siple as `img` not the same as `image`

Comment: Check your real paths of images. Check value of $path after storing. I think your paths are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Auth::user()->img` should probably be `Auth::user()->image`